# Android google cloud messaging sample not working

Tags: cloud, messaging, google-cloud-messaging

Im following the tutorial here http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html in order to setup GCM.
Im currently in the process of trying to register the device.
However, for some reason, the application always seems to crash at 
gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

The stacktrace seems to point at the following: 
06-18 13:42:20.909: I/dalvikvm(11613): Could not find method com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance, referenced from method pushNotification.PushNotification$1.run

Heres a sample of what I have so far

```
public PushNotification(Context c, Activity activity)
{
    context = c;
    this.activity = activity;
    regid = getRegistrationId(context);

    if (regid.length() == 0) {
        Log.d("IN PUSHNOTIFICATION ","NOT REGISTERED. REGISTERING NOW.....");
        registerBackground();
    }
    Log.d("IN PUSHNOTIFICATION ","REGISTRATION COMPLETE.....");
    Log.d("IN PUSHNOTIFICATION ","REGISTRATION ID IS: " + regid);
    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(activity); //never reaches this code

}

private void registerBackground() {

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            String msg = "";
            try {
                if (gcm == null) {
                    Log.d("IN PUSHNOTIFICATION", "IN BACKGROUND. gcm == NULL");
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                    Log.d("IN PUSHNOTIFICATION", "IN BACKGROUND. AFTER gcm.GETINSTANCE");
                }
                Log.d("IN PUSHNOTIFICATION", "IN BACKGROUND. BEFORE gcm.register");
                regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                msg = "Device registered, registration id=" + regid;
                Log.d("IN PUSHNOTIFICATION", "IN BACKGROUND. regid == " + regid);
                // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP,
                // so it can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.

                // For this demo: we don't need to send it because the device
                // will send upstream messages to a server that echo back the message
                // using the 'from' address in the message.

                // Save the regid - no need to register again.
                setRegistrationId(context, regid);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.d("IN PUSHNOTIFICATION", "IN BACKGROUND. EXCEPTION ERROR ERROR: ex = " + ex.getMessage());
                msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
    );
    thread.start();
}
```

Here is the full stacktrace

> 06-18 13:42:20.909: D/IN PUSHNOTIFICATION(11613): NOT REGISTERED.
>   REGISTERING NOW..... 06-18 13:42:20.909: I/dalvikvm(11613): Could not
>   find method
>   com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance,
>   referenced from method pushNotification.PushNotification$1.run 06-18
>   13:42:20.909: W/dalvikvm(11613): VFY: unable to resolve static method
>   5967: Lcom/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging;.getInstance
>   (Landroid/content/Context;)Lcom/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging;
>   06-18 13:42:20.909: D/dalvikvm(11613): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at
>   0x0015 06-18 13:42:20.909: I/dalvikvm(11613): Could not find method
>   com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.register, referenced
>   from method pushNotification.PushNotification$1.run 06-18
>   13:42:20.909: W/dalvikvm(11613): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method
>   5969: Lcom/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging;.register
>   ([Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; 06-18 13:42:20.909:
>   D/dalvikvm(11613): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0039 06-18
>   13:42:20.909: D/IN PUSHNOTIFICATION(11613): REGISTRATION COMPLETE.....
>   06-18 13:42:20.909: D/IN PUSHNOTIFICATION(11613): REGISTRATION ID IS: 
>   06-18 13:42:20.909: D/AndroidRuntime(11613): Shutting down VM 06-18
>   13:42:20.909: W/dalvikvm(11613): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x2b542210) 06-18 13:42:20.909: D/IN
>   PUSHNOTIFICATION(11613): IN BACKGROUND. gcm == NULL 06-18
>   13:42:20.909: W/dalvikvm(11613): threadid=20: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x2b542210) 06-18 13:42:20.909:
>   I/Process(11613): Sending signal. PID: 11613 SIG: 9 06-18
>   13:42:20.919: I/ActivityManager(278): Process com.gotoohlala (pid
>   11613) has died.

Comment: Did you [setup the Google play services SDK](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)?

Comment: I believe so. I have google-play-services_lib added as a reference to the project. Im also using GoogleMaps v2 in another package of the project, which runs just fine. So im pretty sure i have google play servies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem.
Although I was linking to google-play-services_lib project, I also had to add the jar file, google-play-services_lib.jar into the project.

Comment: In my case i didn't have the latest android-play-services installed on my device

Answer (score 1):

For the other people may get crazy for this bug like me.
These following error mean the same thing:

Could not find method com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance
java.lang.NoClasDefFound: .....GoogleCloudMessaging

> > > The jar file for GoogleCloudMessaging class does not exported to the android runtime.

Because by default, Android builder does not export jar files frome the `Android Private Library`

You can double check by looking at the `bin/dexedLibs` folder, if you still can not see the `google-play-services-4064834317375a1fffbbc48c3994c697.jar`   <-- that file is not exported to run time.

Solution:
`Project Properties/Java Build Path/Order and Export/`   check the `Android Private Library`
Now your all your jar files will come along to android device, and runtime error will no longer occur.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the push notification through Microsoft Azure platform and faced the same problem.

I solved the problem by checking the 8 steps here:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-get-started-push/#add-push

More precisely, the problem was that library `google-play-services-lib` was not correctly added, even if I added the jar file (Steps 6 and 7)